# Meaning of by way of and start over

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from a novel by Upton Sinclair, King Coal, 1917:

> He was given the use of the building, **by way of start over the saloons**, which had to pay a heavy rental to the company.

He spoke about a clergyman employed by a mining company, I don't understand what he has to do with the saloons, to get the use of the building.

Can someone help ?

Comment: It means the clergyman was given use of the building, rent-free, *in order to give him an advantage* over the saloons, who had to pay high rent for their use of the property. Whoever granted him the space wanted the church (representing morality and godliness) to prevail over the saloons (representing immorality and iniquity) in the hearts of the people of the town.

Comment: (That is, at best, very obscure language.)

Comment: @HotLicks, I imagine it's more archaic/obsolete than deliberately obscure. I suppose if "*start*" we're simply replaced by "*headstart*", the meaning would be immediately accessible and plain to modern readers.

Comment: @HotLicks it would have been less obscure at the time. "Head start" came into this sense about 50 years before this was written and has since become more commonly used in such a case, but even now "we got a start on them" and similar would be common enough in some people's use.

Comment: It's not just the use of "start", but "by way of" (used in a backwards sense from the modern understanding), and the lack of an article.  I've only read a little Sinclair, but my recollection is that he was fond of obscure language.

Comment: @HotLicks oops. It actually missed that that bit was asked about too. A similar point applies, that it was once much more common. The idiom "by way of apology" is a retention of this "for the purpose of" sense.

Comment: @DanBron & JonHanna Thanks. It's much more clear to me now.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you elaborate a bit on how the meaning of "by way of" is reversed here? To my ear, seems like the straightforward application of the phrase in its usual (modern) sense of "as". Though I agree the lack of an article does make the clause harder to parse; I suspect that was a typographical or editing error. Would be weird if it were deliberate.

Comment: @DanBron - The modern use of "by way of" is to identify an enabling facility or route.  It would be quite understandable (if a little overdone) to say that he was "given a start over the saloons by way of free rent of the building" (and in that case even the omitted article would be less confusing).

Comment: @HotLicks I see what you mean now. I didn't find the use of "by way of" odd here, but it's also true that no common modern example of it commuted this way comes to mind, either.

Comment: @DanBron - I'll admit that "by way of apology" uses the phrase in the reversed sense, but that's a set phrase in itself.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't see how you'd call that "reversed". It seems to me to be too different entirely for that, not having an ordering of the sort the other sense has.

Comment: @Jon, I dunno, the example works for me. It's similar to "*by way of [an] explanation*", "*by way of a reward*", etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Start* in this sense means an initial advantage. I have an advantage over you at doing something quicker if I start earlier or start further along in the task, and this can apply figuratively to anything that gives someone an initial advantage. (Compare "head start").

The saloons would have been a competitor for the attentions of the clergyman's potential flock. They would likely have been a competitor in other ways depending on how liberal the clergyman was or was not when it came to the topic of alcohol, and on how many things happened in them that even a clergyman who tolerated liquor would object to.

*By way of* means (among other senses), "for the purpose of". Which is to say this rent-free arrangement was offered with the intention of providing this advantage.